# Understanding Virtual Functions when Deriving from Multiple Classes

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, undefined-behavior, virtual-functions, reinterpret-cast

I have started to understand the working of virtual functions in `C++` and have come across the following code. Here is my understanding about virtual functions:

1. Every class that has defines a virtual function, has a **vtable** created for it.
2. When a instance of a class is created, `vptr` is created, which points to the **vtable** of that class.

Based on my understanding, I am trying to analyse the output of the following code, which i am not able to decipher how the code prints "C12g".

```
class I1 {
  public: 
    virtual void f(){cout << "I1" << endl;}
};
class I2 {
  public: 
    virtual void g(){cout << "I2" << endl;}
};
class C12 : public I1, public I2 {
  public:
    virtual void f(){cout << "C12f" << endl;}
    virtual void g(){cout << "C12g" << endl;}
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  I2 *o = new C12();
  ((I1*)o)->f();
}
```

I thought that, since the `C12` object is assigned to type `I2`, object `o` can access only its method `g()` in `C12` (since g is overridden). Now, since `o` is type-cast to an `I1`, I thought `f()` in `C12` will get called.

Actual output:
C12g

I would like to know about the following things:

1. Memory layout of C12 and what I1, I2 points to
2. How C12g gets printed as output.
3. What happens when an object is type-cast between two unrelated interfaces?

Comment: I suggest you read the following [article](https://hownot2code.com/2016/08/12/good-and-bad-sides-of-virtual-inheritance-in-c/).

Especially focus on "Virtual Base Classes and Type Conversion" towards the end of the article.

Comment: @WitHeld I did go through the article. It talks about virtual inheritance, not virtual functions.

Comment: "_Every class that has defines a virtual function, has a vtable_" I suppose you mean "in practice..." as in theory any implementation technique that produce the specified semantics is allowed. In practice all real world compilers use vtables, but they are specified in the std.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you must first understand here is that the ***actual object*** created, `*o` is of type `C12` - because that's what you constructed with `new C12()`.

Next, with virtual functions, then the member for the ***actual object*** will be called, no matter what 'type' you cast a pointer to. So, when you cast to an `I2` pointer in `I2 *o = new C12()`, it doesn't matter to the underlying object if, for example, you then call o->g(), as the object would 'know' to call its overridden function.

However, when you the cast the pointer to the 'unrelated' `I1*` you get into strange ground. Bearing in mind that the classes `I1` and `I2` have, essentially, identical memory layouts, then calling `f()` in one would be directing to the same 'offset' as calling `g()` in the other. But, as `o` is actually a pointer to `I2`, the v-table entry the call ends up with is the offset of `g` in I2 - which is overridden by `C12`.

It's also noteworthy that you've used a C-style cast to get from `I2*` to `I1*` (but you could also use a `reinterpret_cast`). This is important, because both of these ***do absolutely nothing*** to the pointer, or to the object/memory pointed to.

Probably sounds a bit garbled, but I hope it offers some insight!

Here's a ***possible*** memory layout/scenario - but it's going to be implementation-specific, and using the class pointer after the C-style cast may well constitute undefined behaviour!

### Possible memory map (simplified, assuming 4-bytes for all components):

```
class I1:
0x0000: (non-virtual data for class I1)
0x0004: v-table entry for function "f"

class I2:
0x0000: (non-virtual data for class I2)
0x0004: v-table entry for function "g"

class C12:
0x0000: (non-virtual data for class I1)
0x0004: v-table entry for function "f"
0x0008: (non-virtual data for class I2)
0x000C: v-table entry for function "g"
0x0010: (class-specific stuff for C12)
```

Now, when you do the conversion from a `C12*` to `I2*` in `I2 *o = new C12();`, the compiler understands the relation between the two classes, so `o` will point to the `0x0008` offset in C12 (the derived class has been correctly 'sliced'). ***But*** the C-style cast from `I2*` to `I1*` doesn't change anything, so the compiler 'thinks' it points to an `I1` but it's still pointing to an actual `I2` slice of `C12` - and this 'looks' just like a real `I1` class.

### Homework Assignment

What you may find interesting (and may or may not concur with the memory layout I've described) is to add the following code towards the end of `main()`:

```
C12* properC12 = new C12();// Points to the 'origin' of the class
I1* properI1 = properC12; // Should (?) have same value as above?
I2* properI2 = properC12; // Should (?) have an offset to 'slice'
I1* dodgyI1 = (I1*)properC12; // Will (?) have same value as properI2!
cout << std::hex << properC12 << endl;
cout << std::hex << properI1 << endl;
cout << std::hex << properI2 << endl;
cout << std::hex << dodgyI1 << endl;
```

Please - anyone who tries - let us know what the values are, and what platform/compiler you are using.  In Visual Studio 2019, compiling for the x64 platform, I get these pointer values:

```
000002688A9726E0
000002688A9726E0
000002688A9726E8
000002688A9726E0
```

... which (sort of) concurs with the memory layout I described (other than having the v-tables somewhere else, rather than 'in-block').

Comment: I am able to get a little insight. Can you explain more with memory layouts of C12, I1 , I2 along with  ((I1*)o)->f() ?

Comment: That sounds *possible* that the layout is the same, but I'm concerned that casting as the OP does is actually undefined behavior. I'd be nice if you or I (or someone else, I recon) could site a source whether this is UB or not.

Comment: @Chipster I'll try to find a reference but I *think* it's in the standard that component super-classes are arranged essentially as I have them: in declaration order, and at the very beginning of the derived class memory.

Comment: @user7937993 I've added a possible memory layout! Hope this helps.

Comment: What is "non-virtual data"?

Comment: @curiousguy For example, could be the address of a non-virtual member function.

Comment: @Adrian Which compiler puts that in the vtable?

Comment: @curiousguy None that I know of! But I don't imply that in my (very loose) possibly memory map. I have two sections for each class: non-virtual stuffs and then the vtable. More likely, though, is that the vtables are merged into one, after all the super-class inclusions.

Comment: @Adrian At the end of day, stuff may end up next to one another in memory, but unless you can't expect to always find something at a known offset from a vptr, it isn't a vtable field. BTW the vtable is a record (struct) not a table (array), but all field have usually the same size so it looks like an array of (long) words.

Comment: @curiousguy Your points are all well-founded but, to be frank, rather off-topic. The memory layout I gave was never intended to be precise, and nor did I ever claim it was. The outline given was to illustrate the point of object slicing, and the inherent dangers of C-style casting one pointer type to another.

Comment: @Adrian The issue is that you don't exactly describe what's part of the vtables, so your answer might be seen as confusing.

Comment: @Adrian That gave me an idea of how things could happen. Thanks.